# Using result from a multi select listbox as query where clause

Tags: ms-access, file-access

This is my first post so please excuse me if I'm not yet up to par with all the conventions.

Question is as follows, I have just started creating MS Access databases and I have gotten pretty good at it, I have just recently finished up a whole project and I am currently in middle of creating the reports, I am trying to create a filter form with a tab control and on each page a multi select listbox which is prepopulated with data from the tables, I can't create the filters using buttons or similar since I want it to be dynamic, the filters have to support multiple criteria, I am trying to use the results of the selections of the listbox in a query using the result of my code which I created a string of numbers separated using commas (I haven't quoted the numbers since I am comparing them to numeric fields). I loop thru all the selected items in the listbox and I add them to each other separated by a comma

```
lstSel = lstSel & listbox.itemdata(index) &","
```

I then truncate the final comma using

```
lstSel = left(lstSel,Len(lstSel)-1)
```

And I pass the value into a textbox on my form which I am trying to use in my query with
`where [ID] in(Forms!myForm!myTxtbxResult)`
I don't get any errors I requery the controls and the reports but no avail

Comment: Have a look at this tip provided by Allen Browne bypassing any need for a query: [Use a multi-select list box to filter a report](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-50.html)

Comment: How to ask good questions http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and take the tour http://stackoverflow.com/tour.

Comment: It doesn't work because Access sees textbox content as just a string of characters, not a set of discrete elements. The method shown in the Allen Browne article referenced by @Rene is really the only way to dynamically build and use the SQL IN operator. Instead of dynamic parameterized query, set the WHERE CONDITION argument of DoCmd.OpenReport method.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I didn't get a chance yet to try it... But thanks for giving me the direction!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this tip provided by Allen Browne bypassing any need for a query: [Use a multi-select list box to filter a report](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-50.html)

Comment: The key part being that the elements within the `in` argument need to be delimited with double-quotes, which is a reserved character.

Comment: Apostophes can be used for element delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a pretty old question, but if anyone else is struggling with this I have used the IN operator dynamically by adding single quotes around the strings.

```
lstSel = lstSel & listbox.itemdata(index) &","
```

This would result in a query that looks like this

```
Select * From ... IN(str1,str2,str3,...)
```

Which isn't the proper syntax for IN() (see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)).

However, this-

```
lstSel = lstSel & "'" & listbox.itemdata(index) & "'" &","
```

This would show

```
Select .... IN('str1','str2','str3',...)
```

Which should solve the issue

Comment: Still cannot be passed to a query object by referencing textbox holding that string. The apostrophes are just more text characters. And apostrophes would not be appropriate for a number or date/time field.